# Why transformed the bytecode in the SpiderMonkey & JSC?

Tags: javascript, interpreter, bytecode, native-code, spidermonkey

Javascript engine is usually used to transform bytecode from source code.then, the bytecode transforms to native code.

1) Why transformed bytecode ??   source code directly transforming native code  is poor performance ?
2) If source code is very simple (ex. a+b function), source code directly transforming native code  is good ?

Answer (score 1):

**Complexity and portability**.

Transforming from source code to and kind of object code, whether it's bytecode for a virtual machine or machine code for a real machine, is a complex process. **Bytecode more closely mimics what most real machines do, and so it's easier to work with**: better for optimizing the code to run faster, transforming to machine code for an even bigger boost, or even turning into other formats if the situation calls for it.

Because of this, it usually turns out to be easier to write a *front end* whose only job is to transform the source code to bytecode (or some other *intermediate language*), and then a *back end* that works on the intermediate language: optimizes it, outputs machine code, and all that jazz. **More traditional compilers for languages like C have done this for a long time.** Java could be considered an unusual application of this principle: its build process usually stops with the intermediate representation (i.e. Java bytecode), and then developers ship that out, so that the JVM can "finish the job" when the user runs it.

There are two big benefits to working this way, aside from making the code easier to work with. **The first big advantage is that you can reuse the backend to work with other languages**. This doesn't matter so much for JavaScript (which doesn't have a standardized backend), but it's how projects like LLVM and GCC eventually grow to cover so many different languages. Writing the frontend is hard work, but let's say I made, for example, a Lua frontend for Mozilla's JavaScript backend. Then I could tap into all of the optimization work that Mozilla had put into that backend. This saves me a lot of work.

**The other big advantage is that you can reuse the frontend to work with more machines**. This one *does* have practical implications for JavaScript. If I were to write a JavaScript interpreter, I'd probably write my first backend for x86 -the architecture most PCs use- because that's where I'd probably be doing the development work. But most cell phones don't use an x86-based architecture -ARM is more common these days- so if I wanted to run fast on cell phones, I'd need to add an ARM backend. But I could do that, without having to rewrite the whole frontend, so once again, I've saved myself a lot of work. If I wanted to run on the Wii U (or the previous generation of game consoles, or older Macs) then I'd need a POWER  backend, but again, I could do that without rewriting the frontend.

**The bottom line is that while it seems more complex to do two transformations, in the long run it actually turns out to be easier**. This is one of those strange and unintuitive things that pops up sometimes in software design, but the benefits are real.